# ffmpeg convert one image to video

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, pyffmpeg

At the moment I can convert image sequence to video. But the current requirement is to convert one image into a video. And can achieve some special effects.

For example:

1. fade in/out
2. flash in/out
3. pan top/bottom/left/right
4. zoom in/out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zoomin example:

```
ffmpeg -i infile -filter_complex "scale=iw*10:-1,zoompan=z='zoom+0.01':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s={output_width}x{output_height}" -t {duration} -y -shortest -c:v libx264 outfile
```

Comment: 大佬，用这个方法发现速度很慢，scale 放大的越大，越慢，请问有什么解决办法吗？

```shell
ffmpeg -i cat.jpeg -filter_complex "scale=iw*4:-1,zoompan=z='zoom+0.002':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=720x960" -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 28 -y -t 5 out.mp4
```

这是我目前用的命令